# OpenFDA End Point Updates

Tags: api, openfda, releasing-data

With respect to the [US Food and Drug Administration's API](https://open.fda.gov/), I haven't seen the endpoints updated since 8/12/19.  Did something change or is this common?  I've noticed the endpoints refreshed fairly regularly over the past 6 months.

Comment: please note that this is a worldwide forum and not specific to any platform or country. please contact the data provider if the question can't be answered by the open data community.

Comment: We use the endpoint for MAUDE data and I've noticed the same. Usually the previous month's data is in there by the middle of the month. Curiously the web interface has August data. I have emails in to them and reached out on Twitter (@openFDA) - if I hear anything I will update.

Comment: On the [status page](https://open.fda.gov/about/status/) it says, *“Currently, there is a temporary suspension of updates to the openFDA datasets. Please send inquiries regarding this matter to: open@fda.hhs.gov”*. I just spent six months building an application based on this data, so I really hope this is indeed temporary. 

Comment: I have this update from Lonnie Smith at openFDA: *“The suspension of automatic updates to openFDA is temporary. OpenFDA is fully operational during the temporary submission of automatic updates' timeframe as we strive to ensure that the openFDA platform is in alignment with new requirements.”* 