# OpenFDA API Suspension effective 12/20/2019?

Tags: openfda

I'm wondering if anybody has any knowledge around the current suspension. None of the APIs have been updated since 12/14/2019, and the API status page currently reads, "Currently, there is a temporary suspension of updates to the openFDA datasets. Please send inquiries regarding this matter to: open@fda.hhs.gov" (this text was merged in to the github repo on 12/20).

I've reached out to open@fda.hhs.gov and haven't gotten a response.

Does anybody know what the suspension cause is, when it might be lifted, or what events would trigger it getting lifted?

Comment: Related? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/15676/1511

Comment: I have this update from Lonnie Smith at openFDA: *“The suspension of automatic updates to openFDA is temporary. OpenFDA is fully operational during the temporary submission of automatic updates' timeframe as we strive to ensure that the openFDA platform is in alignment with new requirements.”* 

Answer (score 3):

I'm Jack with the openFDA Team. The temporary suspension of updates to the openFDA datasets has ended. We're in the process of updating all datasets. Please stay tuned in to the [API Status page](https://open.fda.gov/about/status/) for update details. Thank you!